# Problemas con el servidor angular

Tags: nodejs, angular

Hace poco empece hacer una aplicación web en angular, y ahora retome el proyecto, la cuestión es que quiero compilar entrando a http://localhost:4200/ y no me aparece nada, no me compila el proyecto, no se como subirlo al servidor, intenten de todo, o no se si buge el node js ! ayuda.

Comment: Gabriel! te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Comment: Al iniciar el servicio con ng serve te da algun error? Algo?

Comment: si me da un error. node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`

Answer (score 3):

Si tenias el proyecto en algún control de versiones (gitlab,github,etc) y volviste a clonarlo, debes hacer un

```
npm install
```

para descargar todas dependencias que necesita angular para funcionar, si lo que buscas es correr tu proyecto en modo desarrollo, utiliza el CLI de angular usando el comando

```
ng serve
```

eso levantara un servidor local y podrás correr tu proyecto por lo regular en la dirección http://localhost:4200 (contemplando que no has modificado el .angular-cli.json),por otro lado si lo que deseas es poner en producción tu proyecto debes compilar el proyecto para poder subirlo,si este es tu caso utiliza el comando

```
ng build --prod
```

eso te genera una carpeta **/dist** en la raíz de tu proyecto que es la que necesitas subir a tu servidor de producción

Comment: muchas gracias oscar !